# how do I correct this issue when running go in Wasm

Tags: javascript, system-calls, webassembly

I am following a freecodecamp tutorial to learn how to run go in js environment through wasm. but I got this error when running the following code in my server. Please let me know if you can figure out what went wrong.

```
./main.go:13:36: cannot use sayHi (type func([]js.Value)) as type func(js.Value, []js.Value) interface {} in argument to js.FuncOf
```

package main

```
import (
    "fmt"
    "syscall/js"
)

func sayHi(args []js.Value) {
    fmt.Println("Hi!");
}

func registerCallbacks() {
    js.Global().Set("sayHi", js.FuncOf(sayHi))
}

func main() {
    c := make(chan struct{}, 0)
    registerCallbacks()
    <-c
}
```

Comment: I guess its missing some kind of `this js.Value`?